# Immediate Population of Second Drop Down Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**QUESTION**

Currently, I have a working ajax script which when a value in the first drop down is selected, it runs the ajax script to populate the second drop down. However, the second select does not actually run/populate until you click on that second drop down - the first time you click it, it will say "no results", and then you click on it again, and it loads the list, rather than populating immediately when the first drop down value is selected.

How might I go about making the second drop down populate immediately, or alternatively go about adding a spinner or disable `pet_breed` or something similar until the second drop down loads the values so 'no results' doesn't show after the `type_taxonomy` value has been selected?

I'm sorry but I have very little experience with javascript...

***taxonomy setup***

```
// Custom Taxonomy (First Select Box) - type_taxonomy
parent => false
values => Cat
          Dog

// Custom Taxonomy (Second Select Box) - breed_taxonomy
parent => Cat
child  => Cat Breed 1
          Cat Breed 2
          Etc...
parent => Dog
child  => Dog Breed 1
          Dog Breed 2
          Etc...
```

***existing code - audp-select-breed.js***

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $(function($) {
    
        $('#pet_type').on('change', function() {
        
            var petType = $(this).val();
            
            if ( petType != '' ) {
            
                var data = {
                    'action': 'audp_select_pet_breed',
                    'pet_type': petType
                }
                
                $.post(audp_select_pet_breed_obj.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    $('#pet_breed').html(response);
                });
            
            }
        
        });
    
    });

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/aa180bcf09cd4315aab3e4f06a6cb6ab - Instead of listening to a change on the body itself, we listen to the `#pet_type` which I presume is the first dropdown selector.

Comment: Thank-you for your suggestion but but unfortunately now nothing loads. I've updated my question as my question/problem was in fact not correct.

Comment: instead of calling the ajax every time selection changes in the first dropdown, can you not load all possible values for the second dropdown in the beginning itself as json and use javascript to locally load the values when first dropdown changes?

Comment: in the background, the first select is one taxonomy (type_taxonomy) with 2 values, and the second drop down is another taxonomy (breed_taxonomy) with parent values the same as the two values in type_taxonomy, and then the child terms are the actual breeds under 'cat' and 'dog'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `disabled` functions in the appropriate code lines to ensure that the select box could not be accessed until the data had loaded.

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $(function($) {
        
        $('#pet_type').on('change', function() {
            
            $('#pet_breed').prop('disabled', true);   // Disables While Values Load
            var petType = $(this).val();
            
            if ( petType != '' ) {
            
                var data = {
                    'action': 'audp_select_pet_breed',
                    'pet_type': petType
                }
                
                $.post(audp_select_pet_breed_obj.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    $('#pet_breed').html(response);
                    $('#pet_breed').prop('disabled', false); // Enables After Values Load
                });
            
            }
        
        });
    
    });

})( jQuery );
```